# Using MonoCross, where should the creation of SQLite databases live?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monocross

Due to the differences in file structure etc. between platforms, I was wondering if the database creation (with connection strings) need to be platform specific? Or if there's maybe a way to create a database from OnAppLoad() platform agnostic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SQLite file format](http://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html) is fully portable.

> A database in SQLite is a single disk file. Furthermore, the file
>   format is cross-platform. A database that is created on one machine
>   can be copied and used on a different machine with a different
>   architecture. SQLite databases are portable across 32-bit and 64-bit
>   machines and between big-endian and little-endian architectures.

You do not need to worry about it at all. Things to worry about that are not platform related are few and can include the WAL journal-mode due to lack of backward compatibility.

You can also read:

http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html#sect_9_0

and:

http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#how_to_corrupt